# What are some ways to prove that product of $n$ elements in a group does not change its value no matter how many parentheses there are?

Tags: group-theory, associativity

In the book I am reading it is written:

> The *associative law* was enunciated only for three elements, but can in fact be easily proved in its more general form, namely that, without ambiguity,
>
> $(A_1A_2...A_r)(A_{r+1}...A_n)=(A_1A_2...A_s)(A_{s+1}...A_n)$, where $r$ and $s$ are any two integers between $1$ and $n$.

There, this is proved with the help of mathematical induction, and I strongly dislike induction-based proofs because of some reasons.

But, to leave aside my personal feelings about method of mathematical induction, I am not satisfied with this generality and I think that it should be proved, if true, that the product of $n$ elements in a group does not change its value no matter where are the parentheses and how many of them there are?

In the example above from book there is only one pair of parentheses and I would like to see more general statement than this one from the book.

> So, how to prove (without method of mathematical induction) that the product of $n$ elements in a group does not change its value no matter how many parentheses there are and no matter where are they placed?

Comment: Virtually all proofs in mathematics (even things like $a+b=b+a$ for $a,b \in {\mathbb N}$) depend ultimately on the use of mathematical induction, so you should get over your dislike of it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Isn`t there a difference between "axiom of mathematical induction" and "proof by the method of mathematical induction"?

Comment: The axiom of mathematical induction is the axiom that says that proofs by mathematical induction are valid. To make my previous statement more precise I would assert that any proof of any mathematical statement of the form "for all natural numbers $n$ the statement $P(n)$ is true" (where $P(n)$ depends on $n$) must use mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a(r,s)$ for the product $A_rA_{r+1} \dots A_s$ whenever this is well-defined. We know that it is well-defined (doesn't depend on bracketing) for products of two or three elements.

Now suppose we have a counterexample of minimal length. So that with $r\le s\lt n$ $$\left(a(1,r)\right)\left(a(r+1,n)\right)\neq \left(a(1,s)\right)\left(a(s+1,n)\right)$$taking the outermost brackets in each product. We can't have $r=s$ because the products would be the same, so $r\lt s$ and we can write $$\left(a(1,r)\right)\left(a(r+1,s)a(s+1,n)\right)\neq \left(a(1,r)a(r+1,s)\right)\left(a(s+1,n)\right)$$ because we can bracket the shorter terms however we like by minimality. And this inequality contradicts the associative law.

But then there are as many reasons to dislike proof by contradiction as proof by induction, and the inductive property of the natural numbers is always behind their use in proofs like this. eg How do you prove that any non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element? See [this question](http://476774) for the answer to that.

Comment: Why do you suppose that we have a counterexample of minimal length? Why is minimal length important?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Minimal length is important because it means you can ignore brackets in shorter expressions and confidently group shorter expressions as you wish. Without that there is no reason to think that shorter expressions can be regrouped.

Comment: By taking a counterexample of minimal length, you are actually using mathematical induction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hence the reference to the linked question which makes this point. On the other hand well-ordering might be taken as an axiom - but that doesn't avoid the core issue, just renders it less visible.